# for MuiPhoneNumber, how can you restrict it to only one country code?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How can I restrict it to only have one country code and the user will not be able to pick other countries?
<MuiPhoneNumber
fullWidth
label="Phone Number"
data-cy="user-phone"
defaultCountry={"us"}
/>

Answer (score 0):

Just pass one country code in **onlyCountries** array. Looks like:

```
<MuiPhoneInput
  onlyCountries=['es']
/>
```